# MS Word with Excel as data source

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to use an excel file as a data source for an ms word document:

- More than one sheet (table) of the excel files need to be displayed in the word file
- Formatting of the tables in MS and excel must look different. I want to use excel to input data and word to create a report of the data.

**Update**

So far I have a word document and an excel document. The first sheet of the excel file appear in the document by: *Insert -> Object -> Excel file (using link to file)*.

What is missing is too insert an object (as above) to the same file but so that the second sheet in the excel file is displayed in word.

Even better will be if the sheet to displayed is identified by sheet name.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: You can try to copy from excel and paste as link in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For a single set of fields**

As suggested by @Scorpio99, copy the cell from Excel, and paste using Paste Special > Paste Link in Word. For an example, see [this guide](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/158-linking-excel-data-into-word-documents), or this [Microsoft Office support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Link-or-embed-data-cf1c1ba3-03d1-44d5-a24a-f01a752c57b5).

**For multiple sets of fields**

If the data has multiple entries (e.g. a list of names and addresses for a dozen recipients), use [Mail Merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3). This is designed to generate output in bulk (e.g. address labels), but can be used to generate any sort of Word layout repeatedly, using an Excel data set.